# Qt scrolling a large image

Tags: c++, qt, audio, graphics, scroll

I need to implement a simple sound editor with a specific signal processing function. 
I want to display the sound information vertically as a large picture - 1024 x [large height]. 
So I'm looking for Qt's best way to implement low-cpu-consuming vertical scrolling similar to web-browsers scrolling.

Comment: How are you creating the image?  If it is just the signal waveform, then create it using QGraphicsScene/View and then you can take advantage of the inbuilt spatial acceleration structures and OpenGL rendering of it.

Comment: I will draw image while reading file. it will be a spectrum like http://lh4.ggpht.com/-crInga_olaA/RsYYBZsINOI/AAAAAAAAABo/qww0I98IBMk/data_acquisition.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom widget by overriding it's `paintEvent()`.
Have a look at [this self-explanatory example](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/qt4tutorial/customwidget/) on how to create a following widget.

[image]

Comment: Custom widget? But does Qt able to give some useful scroll facilities? Why do i need custom widget? Can i use some built-in drawing facilities combined with scrolling facilities? Something like: (1) draw some image in memory, (2) insert that image into a scrolling area?

Comment: Because what you want to achieve falls under custom widget. You're talking about visible custom Qt widget - hence I offer you what I'd would choose. If you want to expand your custom widget to have scrolling capabilities, you can inherit your custom widget from `QAbstractScrollArea`, so the scroll area and the scrollbars will be part of the widget. Then you just put your image on top of widget visible area using `paintEvent()`. Pretty straight forward. Sure, if you want to implement zoom and other functionality, it will require some additional work.

Answer (score 0):

A normal QScrollArea will give you what you want 99% of the time.  But you're wanting to create a bitmap of potentially massive size, and you want to store it in RAM - you will quickly run out of space.

You are probably going to need a need a system where you save the image to file, and use the scroll area's bounds to intelligently load it's contents from the file (and a certain size around it to make it smooth) - Qt does not provide this.  This is hardly groundbreaking stuff, so a web search for "scrolling very large images" or something similar should give a smart result.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to plot STFT data, then you can easily adopt one of the widgets in the QWT library:

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

Anyway, take a look at it, it is a great source of inspiration and the code is available...